# Why does Silverlight Add Service Ref. use eventing instead of IAsyncResult?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, asynchronous, service-reference

Ye Olde Add Web Reference generates XXXAsync calls to services that use eventing to inform the caller that the call had completed.

Add Service Reference in something like a WPF or console app, when told to generate async operations, uses the IAsyncResult design pattern (BeginXXX and EndXXX operations). My understanding is that this was generally regarded as a step forward in usability and flexibility - you can use a callback, you can begin blocking at any point in time simply by calling EndXXX, you can group wait handles and block on a set of operations, you can poll, etc.

Why doesn't ASR in Silverlight use IAsyncResult? My guess is because the designers wanted to make it very clear that full asynchronicity is in fact required, and if they had used the IAsyncResult design pattern, it would have been too easy to try just call Begin immediately followed by End, which would have made for a stumbling block that would have been hit by roughly 100% of new devs or people who didn't have a good grasp of async.

Comment: The event-based asynchrony pattern is important for UI-based applications, like Silverlight or WinForms, because they deliver notifications on the thread that made the call. This allows you to use an event handler to make an async call and then from the callback make changes to the UI.

Comment: Nope - if you pop open VS2010 and just create a new SL app, create a new WCF service in the server-side project, and do an Add Service Reference, in the SL client you can do myClient.DoWorkAsync, but there's no myClient.BeginDoWork or EndDoWork. I know that if you do it "by hand" via contract sharing instead of using ASR that you end up with Begin and End methods in the client, but I'm mostly curious about why they chose to go with eventing for ASR.

Comment: You can do it a little less 'by hand' if you just cast the proxy to the interface type.  See the 'Alternative Asynchronous Invocation Model and Threading Issues' section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(VS.95).aspx.

Comment: @Kimberly, I didn't even think about that; it didn't even occur to me that the eventing pattern was simply implemented in the proxy. Thanks! @Gabe, your point about the ease of use provided by the event automatically firing on the calling thread is very true and is a good point; thx.

Comment: @Nla Hope it helps you.  I can't speak for Silverlight team, but the fact that they included that section in the MSDN article seems to imply that they did not come to this decision without some hesitation, or at least some expectations of annoying a few developers by it.

Comment: Also, seems like you should ask this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286864/silverlight-wcf-proxy-async-only/1647301#1647301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Silverlight team provided immediate access to the event based async pattern because it's an easier to use approach (but a lot less flexible). For example, the event is fired in the display thread, allowing developpers unwilling to think about their thread model to forget about it.

If you need better flexibility (as me), the Begin/End async pattern is available for Silverlight too. In fact the event based generated code is based upon the IAsyncResult one.

Your generated Channel interface defines the begin/end methods, and you can use the [channel factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms576132(VS.95).aspx) to obtain an usable implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(VS.95).aspx):

> Usually, the event-based asynchronous model described previously raises the completion event on the same thread on which the service was called. This is convenient in many applications, because you often invoke services from the UI (User Interface) thread, and can update UI components (such as text boxes in our example) directly in the completion event handler.
>
> Occasionally, you may want the completion event to be processed on a background thread. Either for this or for other reasons, you may want to use an alternative asynchronous invocation model based on the IAsyncResult mechanism and on Begin/End methods.
>
> To use this model, you must first cast the proxy to an appropriate interface type. The interface type is generated automatically alongside the proxy by the Add Service Reference tool. You can then invoke the appropriate Begin method.
>
> `CopyIAsyncResult iar = ((CustomerService)proxy).BeginGetUser(userId, GetUserCallback, proxy);`

Thanks to Kimberly for the MSDN link.